# Why does a real plane cubic have at most 3 flexes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This statement is from "Ebene algebraische Kurven" by Prof. Gerd Fischer. I assume that he means an irreducible cubic.

Well, to calculate the number of flexes, one intersects the cubic $\mathcal C$ with the Hessian $H_{\mathcal C}$. Since $\deg H_{\mathcal C} = 3(n-2) = 3$, Bezout's theorem implies that there are $\deg H_{\mathcal C} \cdot \deg \mathcal C = 3 \cdot 3 = 9$ intersection points. How do I get this number down to $3$?